# Why must I use reference to return/pass std::ostream?

Tags: c++

Why I got an error with this code :

```
ostream operator<<(ostream flux, Perso const A)
{
    A.O_Show(flux);
    return flux;
}
error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ostream<char>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)'|
```

And no errors with :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& flux, Perso& const A)
{
    A.O_Show(flux);
    return flux;
}
```

Can you explain what's the difference?

Comment: `std::ostream` is [not copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream). Are you asking why this is?

Comment: "And no errors with:" - Did you even try compiling that?

Answer (score 2):

As for your code

```
ostream operator<<(ostream flux, Perso const A) {
    A.O_Show(flux);
    return flux;
}
```

You cannot copy a [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream) as return value (prior to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standards, and even these are `protected` in 1st place), just change your code to

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& flux, Perso& const A) {
    // ^
    A.O_Show(flux);
    return flux;
}
```